# rich:toolTip not handling String values that contain quotes

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have ran into a particularly strange problem when implementing a RichFaces tool tip component.  In my project I have a table that displays a list of Strings that are entered by the user, and I want there to be a pop-up of additional information when a user mouses over the strings in the list.

One of the requirements is that any string that is more than one word must contain double quotes `""` when input by the user--e.g. a single word would be input as `Java` vs. a phrase `"Java is cool"`.

So, I added a `<rich:toolTip>` to render additional info if it exists--**and it works**, except for strings that contain double-quotes.  For example (as it's displayed in the table) `"sample string"` will not show additional information on mouseover.

My JSF code is simply:

```
<h:outputText id="keywordText" value="#{keywordData.keyword}"/>
<rich:toolTip for="keywordText" rendered="#{keywordData.comments != null}" value="#{keywordData.comments}"/>
```

Like I said, this works for words/strings that do not contain quotes.  I am wondering if there is a workaround within JSF/RichFaces I can use in order to get this to work properly with a string that contains quotes.  Or perhaps some assistance in writing a custom JavaScript function that forces or "tricks" RichFaces into handling quotation marks in a string correctly?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**Edit:**  I am using RichFaces 3.3.3

In the page source, for the string `"Testing Quotes"` (does not work) I found this:

```
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":keywordText">"Testing Quotes"</span>
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":j_id159" class="rich-tool-tip " style="z-index:99; ">
    <span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":j_id159content">
        <p>This comment should display</p>
    </span>
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":j_id159script" style="display:none">
<script id="scriptj_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:" quotes":j_id159"="" testing="" type="text/javascript">
    new ToolTip("j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":j_id159","j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":keywordText",{'showEvent':'mouseover'} );
</script>
</span>
```

**You can see that the quotations in the string itself (which appears to supposed to be part of the id attribute) are being misinterpreted in the `new ToolTip` parameters**.  And for a string `testkeywordawesome` without quotes you can see it works (because it does not contain quotes):

```
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:keywordText">testkeywordawesome</span>
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:j_id159" class="rich-tool-tip " style="z-index: 99; visibility: hidden; display: none; left: 63.7833px; top: 210.75px;">
    <span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:j_id159content">
        <p>the best comment in the world</p>
    </span>
<span id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:j_id159script" style="display:none">
<script id="scriptj_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:j_id159" type="text/javascript">
    new ToolTip("j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:j_id159","j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:testkeywordawesome:keywordText",{'showEvent':'mouseover'} );
</script>
</span>
```

**Edit2:**  The tool tips exists in a `rich:column`, of which exists in a `rich:extendedDataTable`.  Below are their code:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{keywordEntry.globalKeywordsDataModel}"
                            rendered="#{fn:length(keywordEntry.globalKeywords) gt 0}"
                            styleClass="removeEDTSortIcon removeEDTContextMenu"
                            id="keywordTable" rowClasses="row1, row2"
                            var="keywordData" rows="0" noDataLabel=" "
                            headerClass="#{displayHeader == null or displayHeader ? 'rich-table-header' : 'hide'}"
                            rowKeyVar="keywordRowIdx" enableContextMenu="false"
                            sortMode="#{globalKeywordListSort.multiSortEnabled ? 'multi' : 'single'}"                   
                            sortPriority="#{globalKeywordListSort.sortOrderList}"
                            width="#{eStaffUser.userKeywordAdmin ? '750px' : '750px'}"
                            height="#{((fn:length(keywordEntry.globalKeywords)*30 + 50) lt 480) ? (fn:length(keywordEntry.globalKeywords)*30 + 50) : 480}px"
                            >
```

and

```
<rich:column id="#{globalKeywordSortFieldEnumBean.KEYWORD}" selfSorted="false" width="#{eStaffUser.userKeywordAdmin ? '48%' : '52%'}" sortBy="#{keywordData.keyword}"
                             sortOrder="#{globalKeywordListSort.dataTableColumnSortClass[globalKeywordSortFieldEnumBean.KEYWORD].sortOrder}">
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't interact with the value. What version of RichFaces are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the root of the issue was that the `rich:extendedDataTable` uses an ID supplied by each entry to generate a unique ID for each table row. So the problem ended up being in the underlying **"Model Managed-Bean"** that implemented a generic data entity interface, this interface defines a `getEntityId()` method and in this case, the "ID" returned was the keyword value itself, since there was no true (i.e., database) entity ID such as a primary key:

```
public class KeywordDataBean implements SummaryDataEntityIF<String>
```

The problem was resolved by changing the interface's implementation to `Integer` and returning the hash as the unique ID for each keyword object:

```
public class KeywordDataBean implements SummaryDataEntityIF<Integer>
```

This forced the html `id` generated by the `rich:extendedDataTable` to be a simple integer number instead of a (keyword) string containing quotes, allowing the `rich:toolTip` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="j_id138:j_id144:keywordTable:"Testing Quotes":keywordText"
```

This means that one of the parents of `<h:outputText id="keywordText">` has its id defined by something that evaluates to `"Testing Quotes"`, that's obviously bad.

Comment: @BalusC The quotes are in the id of `<h:outputText>` as well though, so wherever the issue is it's not in the given code.

Comment: @Makhiel @BalusC I appreciate both inputs.  I'm still not sure if its JSF or RichFaces causing the problem.  I think the `ToolTip` 1st parameter is breaking when it encounters the first quotation mark.  Not to mention the unwanted `quotes` and `testing` attributes generated in the `<script>` tag as well.

Comment: @heez Can you show more code surrounding the tooltip? It looks like the issue in some element that is wrapped around the tooltip.

Comment: @Makhiel I included more code.  The tooltip is in a column inside an extended data table.